# How to reorder the x-axis when 3 different dataframes are used?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get 3 different lines, so there are 3 different dataframes, agg1, agg2, agg3. The data in Daysleft for agg1 is ">60",">70",">80",">100". The data in Daysleft for agg2 is ">80",">100". The data in Daysleft for agg3 is ">100". The x-axis for that graph that I am getting currently is ">100",">60",">70",">80". I have already factorised the Daysleft column correctly for the 3 dataframe. However, after plotting the graph, the x-axis is jumbled up again. Thanks!

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=agg1,aes(x=Daysleft,y=AvgPrice,group=1),colour="red")+
  geom_point(data=agg2,aes(x=Daysleft,y=AvgPrice,group=1),colour="blue")+
  geom_point(data=agg3,aes(x=Daysleft,y=AvgPrice,group=1),colour="green")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with synthetic data, maybe you should give us a reproducible example to work with. Also, the proper way to achieve the plot that you want would be to combine the three dataframes into a unique dataframe with an additionnal column for the grouping.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide some data, I can try it on my side. The following is my approach, please let me know if it does not work with your data.

```
agg1$group = 1
agg2$group = 2
agg3$group = 3

df <- rbind(agg1, agg2, agg3)

df %>% 
  mutate(Daysleft = as.factor(Daysleft, levels = c(">60",">70",">80",">100"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Daysleft, y = AvgPrice, color = group))
```